# Does measurement necessarily add energy to a quantum mechanical system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

When looking at the effect of observation on electrons forming wave patterns or particles, are there any methods of measurement which would not ordinarily be considered as observation, and yet have the *influence* that an active observer would have?

The quantum world seems to react to focused observation. From my limited understanding of the subject, it would seem that the act of focused concentration/observation causes the *quantum* *world itself* to become *focused*, in a layman's way of speaking. Or to look at the flip side of the question: what measurements methods are there, if any, that do *not* have the effect or are completely independent, of observation on the experiment. If not why, and if so what are they?

So in summary: Since I don't think any observer can *see* without *looking*, are any types of measurement that do *not* add energy to the system apart from the presence of an active observer? Any views are appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I suggest you to edit your question and rewrite the title without all-caps.
Also, can donwvoters give reason for their downvote? Thanks.

Comment: @user190081 I find the repeated notion of 'seeing without looking' and 'measuring without observing' strange and lacking in elaboration. When you observe something, you measure it and hence cause the collapse to one eigenstate. Trying to go too deep into that sentence's phrasing just pulls you into circular reasoning and I don't see much that could emerge from that. So the first 2 paragraphs don't seem to get anywhere and then there's a seemingly unrelated question about energy changes during observation.

Comment: Even in the general case, measurements don't necessarily add energy anyway. Measurements can also end up _subtracting_ energy from a particle (as is the case with most particle physics detectors).

Comment: @Chair While this question may have been poorly worded, I think it does get at something rather fundamental about the understanding of quantum mechanics, and something that students would struggle with, and that's this: When learning about quantum mechanics, it is taught that observation changes things. To new ears, that sounds a lot like magic. It reminds me of an old joke, where a man shows a thermos to a child and says it keeps hot things hot and cold things cold, and the child asks how the thermos knows whether to heat or cool. Observation, at a rather fundamental level, involves energy...

Comment: ...exchange. Observation without changing the environment is just fundamentally impossible, as far as physics can tell. No matter how small the camera, it will always cast a shadow. Now as mentioned by others, there are subtractive methods of observation, but I do wish physics professors made more of a point of teaching students *why* there's a connection between observing something and changing something. To the uninitiated, in the words of the late Arthur C. Clarke, "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."

Answer (score 0):

At the quantum level any measurement is an interaction and interactions are described by  four vectors $(E, p_x,p_y,p_z)$ for each particle participating, including the detecting particle . Energy might be exchanged among the particles participating in the measurement, with a positive or negative sign. The [simplest measurements](https://cds.cern.ch/record/39469) are particles in a bubble chamber interacting with the target.

[image: event]

> This event shows real particle tracks from the Big European Bubble Chamber (BEBC), which was used to observe neutrino and hadron beams between 1973 and 1984 from the PS and SPS accelerators. In this event a neutrino interacts with a proton producing an excited D meson. A labeled diagram is seen on the right as the particles spiral in the magnetic field of the detector.

The energy loss of the particles allows the measurement of their mass from the ionisation of the track, the turning in the magnetic field ( taking energy from the field) allows for measuring the momentum, defining the four vectors of the interaction and measuring the D meson. The four vectors measure the original scattering angular and energy distributions that may be fitted to the expectations from the standard model of particle physics.

So it is [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) that enter in the measurement processes.

Answer (score 0):

The quantum world does not react to focused observation, per se.  The concept of "observation" in the QM world derived from the need to relate the concepts and equations which work well in the subatomic quantum world to macroscopic behaviors which we have always considered to be "classical mechanics."  The major interpretations of QM used the term "observation" to describe the process of acquiring a classical measurement from a quantum mechanical system.

Myself, I find it more convenient to think about this in terms of decoherence.  [Decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) is how elements of a quantum system interact in ways which decrease the quantum coherence which is synonymous with the strange quirky wave-like behaviors of QM.  If you decohere a system by introducing a bunch of particles whose states are well modeled as independent random variables, you can calculate the expectation and variance of the system's final state using statistical means and QM equations.

Decohere a system with enough such particles, and the Central Limit Theorem starts to come into play, decreasing the variance to vanishingly small numbers.  Once you can't observe the variance (because it's too small to capture), you might as well treat the whole macroscopic system of particles as though it *has* one state, which is the expectation of that statistical process.

This is what one would consider to be a "measurement" in a quantum decoherence viewpoint.  It's a clever series of interactions with particles in randomized states such that the expectation is very dependent on the initial state of the system being measured, but which has a "classical" value because the system is decoherent enough to not exhibit any non-trivial QM effects.

So with that in play, we can try to address your questions.  We can't really say what methods we have which aren't observations but act like one, because we'd have to pin down precisely what it means to act like an observation.  However, practically speaking, we can say that if you hooked up a measurement device to a system with interesting QM behaviors, interacted with the system, but simply forgot to hook up the cable that relayed the final measurement, that might qualify.  You would have gone through all the steps of an observation, but the one thing you didn't get out of it was any observations of the state (because the information went down a wire that wasn't connected).  Feel free to massage the wording in this paragraph to suit your own definition of "ordinarially not considered as observations" based on the decoherence approach.

Likewise, we can see that we need to bring in a sufficient number of particles with randomized states to do this measurement.  Those particles must not be in the lowest energy state possible, because they are in a random state.  So we must say that we added energy to the system.  However, there are a few ways around this.

One approach is to take the energy back out.  Consider this: you light a fire, then put it out with a CO2 fire extinguisher.  You technically added energy to the system, but then you took it away and left the system with less energy than it started.  Did that qualify as "not adding energy into the system?"

You can also take energy out of the quantum system in a measurement.  You simply need to construct the instrument such that the quantum information conveyed by the observation is in the form of *how much* energy came out of the system and in what ways.  Bubble chambers, for instance, bleed some energy from the charged particles they observe.